# Why is toString always running in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, built-in, strict-mode

I know that according to ECMAScript specification, non-strict methods will have *thisArg* transformed to the global object, if `null` or `undefined` was passed to them.
That's the reason this code logs the window object (in browsers) instead of null:

```
function x() {
    console.log(this);
}
x.call(null);
```

What I don't understand, is why doing the same thing with `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)`, doesn't transform `null` to the global object, but keeps it as `null` and returns the string `[object Null]`.

Is it because `'use strict'` is used in default implementation of `toString` method?
Is every built-in method run in strict-mode?

I couldn't find anything like that in the specification a https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring.

Comment: When you call toString on an object, it always runs in strict mode. This is because the toString method is a native function, and all native functions are run in strict mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is every built-in method run in strict-mode?

Yes. It says so in [§10.3 Built-in Function Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-built-in-function-objects):

"*Built-in functions that are ECMAScript [function objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#function-object) must be [strict functions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#strict-function).*"

This not only implies non-sloppy handling of the `this` argument, but also that these functions have no `.arguments`, `.callee` and `.caller` properties.